# What are the different token types in C++ compilation?

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, compilation, lexer

Walter Bright's article on C++ Compilation talks about these two phrases

"Conversion to preprocessing tokens."
What is the initial token? What does a preprocessing token look like?

"Conversion of preprocessing tokens to C++ tokens"
What is this C++ Token and why wasn't it converted into it at first?

Reference: http://www.drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/228701711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A preprocessing token is an element of the grammar of the preprocessor.  From [lex.pptoken] in the C++ standard:

> *preprocessing-token*:
>
> - *header-name*
> - *identifier*
> - *pp-number*
> - *character-literal*
> - *user-defined-character-literal*
> - *string-literal*
> - *user-defined-string-literal*
> - *preprocessing-op-or-punc*
> - each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
>
> ...
>
> A preprocessing token is the minimal lexical element of the language in translation phases 3 through 6.

So the "conversion to preprocessing tokens" is the process of lexing the translation unit and identifying individual tokens.

C++ tokens (really just "tokens") are listed in [lex.token]:

> *token*:
>
> - *identifier*
> - *keyword*
> - *literal*
> - *operator*
> - *punctuator*

These only exist after all the other translation phases have occurred (macro expansion and so on).

For more information on the entire process, I suggest reading [lex.phases] in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

**A simplier explanation.**

And, you may know, many compilers, have a lexical analysis process, where the source code is split in tokens.

This source code:

```
void main()
{
  int x = -3 - -5;
  printf("Hello World");
} // void main()
```

Is transform into something similar to this:

```
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  TOKEN       |  TEXT            | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  void        | "void"           | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  identifier  | "main"           | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  leftcurly   | "{"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  identifier  | "int"            | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  identifier  | "x"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  assign      | "="              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  minus       | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  integer     | "3"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  minus       | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  minus       | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  integer     | "5"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  semicolon   | ";"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  identifier  | "printf"         | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  leftpar     | "("              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  string      | "Hello World"    | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  rightpar    | ")"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  semicolon   | ";"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  rightcurly  | "}"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  comment     | "// void main()" | 
+--------------+------------------+
```

Each of this pieces of text called "tokens", have a meaning.

---

Sometimes, in other parts of the compilation process, the tokens may be replaced, by anothers tokens:

```
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  TOKEN       |  TEXT            | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  void        | "void"           | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  functiondec | "main"           | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  leftcurly   | "{"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  type        | "int"            | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  variabledec | "x"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  assign      | "="              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  negative    | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  integer     | "3"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  substract   | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  negative    | "-"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  integer     | "5"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  semicolon   | ";"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
| functioncall | "printf"         | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  leftpar     | "("              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  string      | "Hello World"    | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  rightpar    | ")"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  semicolon   | ";"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  rightcurly  | "}"              | 
+--------------+------------------+ 
|  comment     | "// void main()" | 
+--------------+------------------+
```

---

The conversion from "minus" token, to, either "negative sign token", & "substraction token", is a very good example of this "preprocess token" to "final token".

This is a very conceptual explanation. You may want to read a more detailed technical information on your specific compiler documentation.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this. I would have expected some preprocessor examples but this is great as well.